# Is there a way to select how many products there should be shown in a grid by default?

Tags: magento2, grid

By default my list of products (grid) shows 9 products, by it is able to be changed to 15 or 30.

Is there a way in which I can choose to display 30 products by default, when someone loads the site?

Here is a picture of the selection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhKxp.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell me where you want to changes it?Means which pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is an option for this in admin

- Go to **Store->Configuration** from Menu
- Select **Catalog->Catalog** from left
  navigation
- Then under **Storefront** tab there is `Products per Page on Grid Default Value` to set default value

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Store->configuration ->catalog->catalog->Products per Page on Grid/ListDefault Value**
Change value if u  need 
**EX:30**